# Converting between vectors with different allocators

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

I have written a simple C++11 style stateful allocator type. Given

```
template<typename T> class my_allocator {
   // the usual stuff
};

template<typename T> using my_vector = std::vector<T, my_allocator<T>>;

my_vector<int> x;

std::vector<int> y = x; // error
```

What is the best way to allow conversions from a `my_vector` to a `std::vector` using the default allocator? GCC 4.7 (recent svn) says

`error: conversion from 'my_vector<int> {aka std::vector<int, my_allocator<int>>}' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<int>' requested`

Obviously this could be done with, say, a simple conversion function such as

```
template<typename T> std::vector<T> to_std_vec(const my_vector<T>& v)  {
   return std::vector<T>(&v[0], &v[v.size()]);
   }
```

but this seems pretty inelegant. Is there a better solution in C++11?

Move semantics are right out in this situation, of course, but I'd like copy construction and assignment to work without extra noise/typing.

Answer (score 16):

You cannot possibly hope to get around the obvious copy: `std::vector<int> y(x.begin(), x.end();`. The elements in `y` will be allocated by the `std::allocator`, while the elements in `x` were allocated, and will be destroyed, by your own allocator. The two allocators could have entirely unrelated notions of *memory* and *pointers*! There's no reason that the memory storage that's used by one allocator is in any way related to that of the other.

What else then can you do but make a semantic element copy?

If you don't want the old container any more, you should do a *move*, though:

```
std::vector<int> y(std::make_move_iterator(x.begin()),
                   std::make_move_iterator(x.end()));
```

(This will help in case the *elements* have their own allocator which agrees. Not for `int`, of course.)

*Update:* To reinforce the point, please note that the internal data buffer of a `vector<T, Alloc>` is *not* of type `T*`, but rather of type `Alloc::pointer`. There's no reason that those are related types for two distinct allocators.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Thanks! I had literally no idea what it was called and was hoping to fire blindly and hit something :-) (In hindsight the name is sort of obvious...) Why aren't you advocating `make_move_iterator(begin(x))`, by the way?

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps I communicated my problem poorly. Of course I can't do anything but a copy, but I'd like to do so in a way that is syntactically clean. For instance, a conversion function like the one I suggested is verbose. Is there a way to make the 
`std::vector<int> y = x;` line in my example work?

Comment: @JackLloyd: How much simpler that `std::vector<int> y(x.begin(), x.end());` do you want it? That's fairly concise already!

Comment: @Kerrek:  I thought I just **did** advocate `make_move_iterator(begin(x))`! :-)  Although Jack says he needs a copy, not a move, so have to go without `move_iterator`s here.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: No no, I was only referring to the free `begin` function -- I thought that's the Rigth Way to get iterators nowadays :-)

Comment: Oh, completely missed that!  End of day - brain going to bed before body does... ;-)  I can take or leave the namespace scope `begin()`.  Though if you're in a generic context where a built-in array is possible, then it certainly is handy.

Comment: @Kerrek consider for example a my_vector being returned from a function, and the caller wishes to assign it to a std::vector. They would first have to assign it to a my_vector, then make a copy. Perhaps I should have emphasized that I am looking for an *implicit* conversion. Otherwise I would just use the conversion function I mentioned in my original question.

Comment: @JackLloyd: That's what lifetime extension of temporaries is for: `const auto & x = func(); std::vector<int> y(x.begin(), x.end());` Standard containers don't have constructors from containers or ranges only from iterator *pairs*. At best I'd write a generic *range* class plus wrappers to encapsulate an iterator pair and let `v.all()` return `range(v.begin(), v.end())`. I don't think your original conversion functions adds any sort of convenience, though. It's overly restrictive and does nothing that the standard container interface doesn't already provide.

Comment: One can have two different allocator types that can allocate and deallocate the same memory and only differ in accessory functions, like construct. I think it should be allowed to copy (and more importantly) move from vectors with different allocators under some conditions.

Comment: @alfC: Sure, but that's not currently how the standard library is specified. That would be an extension proposal.

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree, vector should be more flexible and accept a constructor from other (vector) types whose behavior is dispatched to the allocator customizations.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I think your only option here is full copy like:

```
std::vector<int> y( x.begin(), x.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 solutions to your problem:

**I.** If your vector 'y' does not exist yet, you could use :

```
std::vector<int> y(x.begin(), x.end());
```

**II.** If your vector 'y' already exist, you could use : (e.g. for a member of a class)

```
this->y.assign(x.begin(), x.end());
```

These 2 ways to fill a vector are not looking the container type. (and therefore the allocator type)

**III.** Another solution is to create a parent class which could be used as an allocator adapter between the std allocator and your own allocator. In this case, your 2 allocators are of the same type, and could be used with vector methods like operator=().

Comment: Why is II better than `this->y = TypeOfY(x.begin(), x.end());` ?

Comment: @DavidDoria it expresses intent and doesn't require naming the type of `y`. Other than that there could be implementation defined benefits with regards to resource reuse