# Use std::vector<double> to access data managed by std::unique_ptr<double[2]>

Tags: c++, stl, unique-ptr

I have a complex class, that holds a big block of `double[2]`-type data managed by a smart pointer like: `std::unique_ptr<double[2]> m_data;` I cannot change the type of the data structure.

I am using a library that gives me a function with the following signature: `bool
func_in_lib(std::vector<double>& data, double& res)`. I cannot change the signature of this function.

I want to pass the data managed by the `unique_ptr` to the function expecting a `vector<double>&` without breaking the connection to my complex class. I want the function to work directly on my `m_data` and not copy the data into a `std::vector<double>` and the copy it back into my complex class, because I have to do this a lot of times.

Is there any way to do this?

---

Here is some code that covers the semantic I want to have. The code line of my concern is

`vector<double> access_vec = /* give access to my_data via vector interface */;`

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//--- This function is given, I cannot change its signature.
bool
func_in_lib(std::vector<double>& data, double& res) {
  //--- check some properties of the vector
  if (data.size() < 10)
    return false;
  //--- do something magical with the data
  for (auto& d : data)
    d *= 2.0;
  res = 42.0;
  return true;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
struct DataType {
  double a = 1.0;
  double b = 2.0;
  double c = 3.0;
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
ostream&
operator<<(ostream& out, const DataType& d) {
  out << d.a << " " << d.b << " " << d.c << endl;
  return out;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
int
main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  int count = 20;
  //--- init and print my data
  unique_ptr<DataType[]> my_data = make_unique<DataType[]>(count);
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    cout << my_data.get()[i];
  //---
  double         result     = 0.0;
  vector<double> access_vec = /* give access to my_data via vector interface */;
  func_in_lib(access_vec, result);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The purpose of unique_ptr will be dead if some other variable or pointer changes its value. why not use the raw pointer or shared for this particular case.

Comment: "*I want the function to work directly on my m_data and not copy the data into a std::vector<double>*" - `std::vector` is a class and there isn't any way to convert a raw `unique_ptr` array to a `std::vector` other than copying it. (It doesn't take values by references either) Maybe you could use `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<double>>` but that would require you to change the signature but `std::vector<double>`, as far as I know, will not be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Umar: I do not want to pass the unique_ptr, I only want to pass the data. I can access the raw pointer with `my_data.get()`. The next step is my problem. I cannot pass this raw pointer to the function, because it expects a reference to a vector. I do not know how to "convert" or cast this pointer into a `std::vector` without copying it.

Comment: @Ruks: I am afraid you are right.

Comment: Why is a vector passed to `func_in_lib` passed by _non-const_ reference? Is that function supposed to fill/update the vector?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes it is. The function in the `func_in_lib` runs some optimization algorithm and manipulates the content of the vector.

Comment: @ThomasWilde Then, there is no way how to "connect" it to a unique pointer. I see the only option in copying. Your data structure is simply not compatible with that function.

Comment: Short answer: no, there is no way to do what you want. C++ does not work this way. `std::vector` always manages its own memory, and will allocate its own memory for its contents. There is no way to "borrow" someone else's memory for a `std::vector`. One of vector's methods is called `resize()`, I'm sure you know what it does. What do you expect this `resize()` to do, with a fixed size array of two doubles, that cannot be changed? Just this simple thought experiment should make you realize that you will need to find some other solution for what you want to do, this cannot be done with a vector.

Comment: If you can't change `func_in_lib` then what can you change?  `DataType` and/or the class that manages it?  Could the implementation of `DataType` be changed such that it's really just a proxy/view over 3 contiguous doubles in a `std::vector<double>`?

Comment: @G.M. I think this is the best solution. I *can* change the class that manages `DataType`. So I have to rewrite this class to use a `std::vector<double>` instead of a `std::uniqur_ptr<DataType[]>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a colleague of mine I found two solutions, that solve my problem.

### Solution 1 - The hacky one

The idea is to use the structure of the underlying implementation of the `std::vector<double>`, which consists *in my case* of 3 members containing 3 pointers to the data of the vector.

1. start address of the data section
2. end address of the data section
3. address of the current maximum capacity of the data section

So I build a `struct` containing these three addresses and use a `reinterpret_cast` to a `std::vector`. This works with the current implementation of `std::vector` on my machine. This implementation can vary, depending on the installed version of the STL.

The nice thing here is, that I can use the interface of `std::vector` without creating it. I also do not have to copy the data into a `std::vector`. I could also take a just part from the initial data stored in my complex class. I can control the manipulated part, by the pointers I send to the struct.

---

This solves *my problem*, but it is a hack. I can use it, because the code is only relevant for myself. I still post it, because it could be of interest for others.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//--- This function is given, I cannot change its signature.
bool
func_in_lib(std::vector<double>& data, double& res) {
  //--- check some properties of the vector
  if (data.size() < 10)
    return false;
  //--- do something magical with the data
  for (auto& d : data)
    d *= 2.0;

  res = 42.0;
  return true;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
struct DataType {
  double a = 1.0;
  double b = 2.0;
  double c = 3.0;
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
ostream&
operator<<(ostream& out, const DataType& d) {
  out << d.a << " " << d.b << " " << d.c << endl;
  return out;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
int
main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  int count = 20;
  //--- init and print my data
  unique_ptr<DataType[]> my_data = make_unique<DataType[]>(count);
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    cout << my_data.get()[i];
  
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
  // HERE STARTS THE UGLY HACK, THAT CAN BE ERROR-PRONE BECAUSE IT DEPENDS ON
  // THE UNDERLYING IMPLEMENTATION OF std::vector<T>
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
  struct VecAccess {
    double* start = nullptr; // address to the start of the data
    double* stop0 = nullptr; // address to the end of the data
    double* stop1 = nullptr; // address to the capacity of the vector
  };

  //---
  DataType*       p_data = my_data.get();
  VecAccess       va{ &(p_data[0].a),                //points at the 'front' of the vector
                      &(p_data[count - 1].c) + 1,    //points at the 'end' of the vector
                      &(p_data[count - 1].c) + 1 };
  vector<double>* p_vec_access = reinterpret_cast<vector<double>*>(&va);
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
  // HERE ENDS THE UGLY HACK.
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  //---
  double dummy = 0.0;   // this is only relevant for the code used as minimum example
  func_in_lib(*p_vec_access, dummy);

  //--- print the modified data
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    cout << my_data.get()[i];

  return 0;
}
```

---

**Update:** Analyzing the assembler code of the second solution shows, that a copy of the content is performed, even though the copy-constructor of the data objects is not called. The copy process happens at machine code level.

### <s>Solution 2 - The move semantic</s>

For this solution I have to mark the Move-Constructor of `DataType` with `noexcept`.
The key idea is *not* to treat the `DataType[]` array as a `std::vector<double>`.
Instead we treat the `std::vector<double>` as a `std::vector<DataType>`. We can
then *move* the data into this vector (without copying), send it to the function,
and move it back afterwards.

The data is not copied but moved `std::vector`, which is faster. Also relevant for my case I can again take a just part from the initial data stored in my complex class.
Drawback with this solution I have to create an additional storage for the
moved data with the correct size.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//--- This function is given, I cannot change its signature.
bool
func_in_lib(std::vector<double>& data, double& res) {
  //--- check some properties of the vector
  if (data.size() < 10)
    return false;
  //--- do something magical with the data
  for (auto& d : data)
    d *= 2.0;

  res = 42.0;
  return true;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
class DataType {
public:
  double a = 1.0;
  double b = 2.0;
  double c = 3.0;

  // clang-format off
  DataType() = default;
  DataType(DataType const&) = default;
  DataType(DataType&&) noexcept = default;
  DataType& operator=(DataType const&) = default;
  DataType& operator=(DataType&&) noexcept  = default;
  ~DataType()  = default;
  // clang-format on
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
ostream&
operator<<(ostream& out, const DataType& d) {
  out << d.a << " " << d.b << " " << d.c << endl;
  return out;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
int
main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  int count = 20;
  //--- init and print my data
  unique_ptr<DataType[]> my_data = make_unique<DataType[]>(count);
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    cout << my_data.get()[i];
  //---
  vector<double> double_vec;
  double_vec.reserve(count * 3);
  //--- here starts the magic stuff
  auto& vec_as_datatype = *reinterpret_cast<vector<DataType>*>(&double_vec);
  auto* start_mv        = &(my_data.get()[0]);
  auto* stop_mv         = &(my_data.get()[count]) + 1;
  //--- move the content to the vec
  move(start_mv, stop_mv, back_inserter(vec_as_datatype));
  //--- call the external func in the lib
  double dummy = 0.0; // is only needed for the code of the example
  func_in_lib(double_vec, dummy);
  //--- move the content to back
  move(begin(vec_as_datatype), end(vec_as_datatype), start_mv);
  //--- print modified the data
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    cout << my_data.get()[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr: Not possible in a standard-compliant way.

It's actually *almost* possible, but `std::allocator` limitations block your way. Let me explain.

- An [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) "owns" the memory it uses for element storage: A vector has the right to `delete[]` the memory (e.g. on destruction, or destruction-after-move, or a `.resize()`, or a `push_back` etc.) and reallocate elsewhere. If you want to maintain ownership by your `unique_ptr`, you can't allow that to happen. And while it's true your mock-implementation of `func_in_lib()` doesn't do any of that - your code can't make these assumptions because it must cater to the function's declaration, not it's body.

But let's say you're willing to bend the rules a little, and assume that the vector won't replace its allocated memory while running. This is legitimate, in the sense that - if you were able to pass the memory for the vector to use somehow, and it replaced the memory region, you could detect that when `func_in_lib()` returns, and then either fix things in the unique_ptr or throw an exception (depending on whether other places in your code hold a pointer to the discarded memory). Or - let's suppose that `func_in_lib()` took a `const  std::vector<double[2]>&` instead of a non-const reference. Our path would still be blocked. Why?

- `std::vector` manages memory through an allocator object. The allocator is a template, so in theory you could use a vector where the allocator does whatever you want - for example, starting with pre-allocated memory (which you give it - from `unique_ptr::get()`, and refusing to ever reallocate any memory, e.g. by throwing an exception. And since one of the `std::vector` constructors takes an allocator of the appropriate type - you could construct your desired allocator, create a vector with it, and pass a reference to that vector.

But alas - your library is cruel. `func_in_lib` isn't templated and can only take the default template parameter for its allocator: `std::allocator`.

- The default allocator used for `std::vector` and other standard library containers is [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator). Now, allocators are a crooked idea generally, in my opinion; but `std::allocator` is particularly annoying. Specifically, *it can't be constructed using a pre-existing memory region for it to use*; it only ever holds memory it has allocated itself - never memory you gave it.

So, you'll never get an `std::vector` to use the memory you want to.

### So what to do?

1. Option 1: Your hack:

   - Figure out the concrete layout of `std::vector` on your system
   - Manually set field values to something useful
   - Use `reinterpret_cast<std::vector>()` on your raw data.
2. Option 2: `malloc()` and `free()` hooks (if you're on a Unix-like system and/or using a compiled which uses libc)

   - See: [Using Malloc Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269659/using-malloc-hooks)

     the idea is to detect the `new[]` call from the `std::vector` you create, and give it your own `unique_ptr`-controlled memory instead of actually allocating anything. And when the vector asks to free the memory (e.g. on destruction), you do nothing.
3. Switch libraries. The library exposing `func_in_lib` is poorly written. Unless it is a very niche library, I'm sure there are better alternatives. In fact, peharps you could do better job writing it yourself.
4. Don't use that particular function in the library;  stick to  lower-level, simple primitives in the library and implement `func_in_lib()` using those. Not always feasible, but may be worth a short.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Here are some thoughts of mine: 2) that could be a solution because I work on a Linux system. 3) FYI it is the ["NonLinear Optimization"](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Deprecated_API_Reference/) library. The guys do a great job implementing the optimization algorithms. I currently use the C++ interface. There is also a C interface, that gives a pointer/memory based interface. 4) I thought about that. Unfortunately most of the code is placed into one giant object type, with a lot private members. Its easier to reimplement *my* classes.

Comment: @ThomasWilde: So, it's possible that the library itself is great, but the C++ wrappers are poor. A known phenomenon. However... it seems [the library is FOSS](https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt/), so you could just use a custom version of it. Or you could ask them to change that interface to taking a pair of iterators, or an `std::span`, or even a pointer+size if they want no templates but compatibility with older C++ versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a reasonable answer but nobody mentioned ( because it surely does not directly answer your question ) C++17 [polymorphic allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44953472/3972710) with std::pmr::vector in the sense that they can easily do half of the work.

**But** unfortunately it is not possible to come back to an usual std::vector

I also came accross an article of  [Bartek's coding blog](https://www.bfilipek.com/2020/06/pmr-hacking.html) from which I stole the code snippet below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>   // pmr core types
#include <vector>            // pmr::vector
#include <cctype>

template <typename T> void MyToUpper(T& vec)    {
    for(auto & cr:vec)
        cr = std::toupper(cr);
}

//https://www.bfilipek.com/2020/06/pmr-hacking.html

int main() {
    char buffer[64] = {}; // a small buffer on the stack
    std::fill_n(std::begin(buffer), std::size(buffer) - 1, '_');
    std::cout << buffer << "\n\n";

    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource pool{std::data(buffer), std::size(buffer)};

    std::pmr::vector<char> vec{ &pool };
    for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ch)
        vec.push_back(ch);
        
    std::cout << buffer << "\n\n";
    
    MyToUpper(vec);
    
    std::cout << buffer << '\n';
}
```

with potential result under coliru (note: c++17)

`_______________________________________________________________`

`aababcdabcdefghabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz______`

`aababcdabcdefghabcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ______`

The article mentioned that the garbage part (aababcdabcdefghabcdefghijklmnop) is due to vector data reallocation while growing.

But what is interesting here is that the operation performed on the vector was indeed done on the original buffer ( abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz => ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ )

Unfortunately the `std::pmr::vector` would not fit your function `func_in_lib(std::vector<double>& data, double& res)`

I think you bought the library and have no access to the code and can not recompile it, but on the contrary you could use *templates* or maybe just tell your provider to add *using std::pmr::vector;* at the beginning of its code...